# Filter Applescript records by property value

Tags: filter, applescript, record

I have a list of Applescript records such as:

```
set mylist to {}
repeat with i from 1 to 8
    set mylist to mylist & {{group:round (i / 3), info:i}}
end repeat
```

I'd like to filter the records by specific property values to split the records list to something like:

```
{{{group:0, info:1}},
 {{group:1, info:2}, {group:1, info:3}, {group:1, info:4}}
 {{group:2, info:5}, {group:2, info:6}, {group:2, info:7}}
 {{group:3, info:8}}}
```

I got my filtered list with this code:

```
set group_values to {}
repeat with rec in mylist
    if group of rec is not in group_values then
        set group_values to group_values & (group of rec)
    end if
end repeat

set r to {}
repeat with group_value in group_values
    set by_group to {}
    repeat with rec in mylist
        if group of rec is equal to contents of group_value then
            set by_group to by_group & {contents of rec}
        end if
    end repeat
    set r to r & {by_group}
end repeat
```

I'd like to know if there is a simplified way to filter records by property values.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit faster...

```
set mylist to {}
repeat with i from 1 to 100
    set mylist to mylist & {{group:round (i / 3), info:i}}
end repeat

set uniqueValues to {}
set filteredList to {}

repeat with aRecord in my mylist
    set rGroup to aRecord's group
    if rGroup is not in uniqueValues then
        set end of uniqueValues to rGroup
        set end of filteredList to {}
    end if
    set end of filteredList's item getOffset(rGroup, uniqueValues) to (aRecord's contents)
end repeat

on getOffset(pValue, searchList)
    script o
        property refList : searchList
    end script
    set searchListCount to count o's refList
    repeat with i from 1 to searchListCount
        if (item i of o's refList) = pValue then return i
    end repeat
end getOffset
```